# Is there any way to hook into the host name used by `git_remote_connect`?

Tags: libgit2

Since libssh2 doesn't read the SSH config file I'm trying to implement my own support for aliases like this:

```
Host github
  HostName github.com
```

and the remote URL uses the host alias like this: `git@github:path/to/repo.git`.

Is there any way to hook into the host name or URL used by `git_remote_connect` or the SSH transport so that I can transform `github` into `github.com`? I was thinking about adding a new callback but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there's already a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually added a [new callback](https://github.com/stinb/libgit2/commit/2c801b92d148bd987c5b1e30b3f090aa1f02c20e) to look up the URL for a remote. It's not in upstream libgit2 but it probably could be if it's useful to anybody else.